# Why does my word counter output the line ` 1`?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Do you know why do I have a "1" printed in the second row of output?

```
def word_map(string):
    dict = {}
    for word in string.split():
        word = filter(str.isalnum, word).lower()
        word = word.split()
        if word in dict:
            dict[word] +=1
        else:
            dict[word] = 1
    return dict

dict = word_map("This is a string , this is another string too")
for k in dict:
    print k, dict[k]
```

result is:

```
a 1
 1
string 2
this 2
is 2
too 1
another 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: **Mandatory Warning** - Don't use `dict` as variable name

Comment: why? PyCharm doesn't show any warning for that

Comment: @MonaJalal It overrides the builtin `dict` function.

Comment: Note that `filter()` changed in Python 3 and no longer returns a string when its input is a string. `''.join(filter(...))` will safely work in Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because one of the elements of the split is `','` which gets filtered to `''`.

So you're doing `dict[''] = 1`.

Assuming you're trying to count the words in a sentence, you need to either check if the word is valid after you filter it, or while you're printing. For example, this will work for you.

```
def word_map(string):
    word_dict = {}
    for word in string.split():
        word = ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, word)).lower()
        if word.strip():
            if word in word_dict:
                word_dict[word] +=1
            else:
                word_dict[word] = 1
    return word_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is being printed for ",".
You have total 10 words including "," (let us consider "," as a word).
So if you see all the counts, that should give the answer.

Comment: I think you are wrong because I am using  `word = filter(str.isalnum, word).lower()`

Comment: @MonaJalal That's exactly why it happens. I don't know why you think that would stop it from being put in the dictionary. You're not checking `word` after you filter it.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution also works:

```
def word_map(string):
    word_dict = {}
    for word in string.split():
        word = filter(str.isalnum, word).lower()
        word = word.strip()
        if word != '':
            if word in word_dict.keys():
                word_dict[word] +=1
            else:
                word_dict[word] = 1
    return word_dict

my_dict= word_map("This is a string , this is another string too")
for k in my_dict:
    print k, my_dict[k]
```

Comment: This is exactly what my answer says, except it strips before the check.

Comment: your answer is accepted. I just wrote my corrected code